# How to declare a json object or array collection with variable size in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I need to create an array or json that can be filled when detects the counter like an auxiliarJson with variable size but i dont know how can i do it

> TypeError: lAttrsPorDia is undefined
>
> lAttrsPorDia[j] = __oATTRS[i];

```js
    var lAttrsPorDia;
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < __oATTRS.length; i++) {
        if (__oATTRS[i].Dia == counter) {
            lAttrsPorDia[j] = __oATTRS[i];
            j++;
            alert(JSON.stringify(lAttrsPorDia));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ to learn the difference between JSON and a JavaScript object. Your question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Your questions can be answered by simply reading the **MDN JavaScriptGuide**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. Either way, you are getting the error because you never assigned a value to `lAttrsPorDia`. How about `var lAttrsPorDia = [];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript arrays already do have variable size:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('Hello');
```